# HOW TO CREATE URL FOR REGISTER USER LIKE GOOGLE BLOG OR freshdesk.com

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i am developing an application in MVC4. My requirement is that how to create user specific url. suppose my website link is www.demosite.com.this site will allow user to register. after register this site will create a different link for each user like google blog or freshdesk.com . if a user register as john then link will create as www.john.demosite.com

So how it is possible in MVC4 or asp.net application please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do this in the IIS settings to allow wildcard subdomains which you can do following the details on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822445/how-do-i-access-wildcard-subdomains-in-localhost-net-mvc-4).

Then the matter of storing valid subdomains to then check against is up to you.