# Wildcard subdomain on localhost using host file

Tags: windows, iis, dns, localhost, subdomain

I'm trying to set up sub-domains on my development machine that runs IIS 7 on Windows 7.

It looks like it is possible by editing `hosts` file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`  by adding line like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 abc.localhost
```

I'm wondering if this could be done without adding a configuration for each sub-domain?

Answer [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872914/37759) sounds like this might be possible but it's not clear to me...

Comment: The usual `/etc/hosts` doesn't support wildcard names so it would surprise me very much if the MS Windows version of this file did. I'm pretty sure you will want to use a local DNS server for this.