# Pointing subdomains to a "directory"

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two questions regarding pointing subdomains to a directory:

1. Currently I run local, but I can run my site on a fake domain i have set up (with hosts file), its called mysite.com. How can i (by server settings?) do so All subdomains will point to / ? Example anders.mysite.com should show mysite.com and asdassdd.mysite.com also.
2. Maybe 1. is not necessary, but how do i by htaccess point anders.mysite.com to mysite.com/anders ? Important notice is that should not redirect.

Why i thought of 1. is because I do not want to specify anywhere in the htaccess or any apache/domain setting, what the subdomain are, since this will be dynamic (created by logged in users in my webapplication)

Currently the users can use mysite.com/anders/ which is a URI they have created, and not a real directory. In the Kohana bootstrap I am then grabbing the URI and showing the relevant user page.

I am using Kohana MVC framework and have this in my htaccess:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /


# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
</Files>


# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> `how do i by htaccess point anders.mysite.com to mysite.com/anders ? Important notice is that should not redirect.`

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^.]+)\.[^:]+:(?!/\1/).*$
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

For 1, in your vhost just add a `ServerAlias`:

```
ServerAlias *.mysite.com
```

Then any subdomain (www included) will get pointed to the same document root.

If you want to put subdomains in their own directory (and since you have access to server config), you can use [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) and the `VirtualDocumentRoot` directive:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /path/to/your/htdocs/%1
```

So if you request `blah.mysite.com`, you'll end up in `/path/to/your/htdocs/blah` as the doc root.

If it's a matter of you needing directory names of non-existent directories in the URI so that Kohana can route them, you'll need to make sure you have mod_proxy loaded:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,P]
```

To proxy the request back to Kohana with the right URI.

Comment: My hosts file have 127.0.0.1 mysite.com and my httpd-vhosts.conf now have:
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias *.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>

but I am still unable to reach to document root on blabla.mysite.com. Am i missing something ?

Comment: To clarify, my needs are that Kohana should read blah.mysite.com/page/stuff like it is mysite.com/blah/page/stuff

Comment: Since I am not really on mysite.com, I have used the hosts file to make the browser think I am.

Comment: @Karem Are you using the proxy rules? in your htaccess file? (and have mod_proxy loaded)

Comment: my htaccess still looks exactly as you can see in the question. I have just activated module proxy for apache on the server now. What should I do now?

Comment: @Karem you need to add the rules that's in my answer, otherwise nothing will get mapped.

Comment: thanks I have now tried that, but now I get a 500 internal error when accessing mysite.com and subdomains asd.mysite.com does still not point to root.

Comment: Ok, so maybe it is working, and it is another issue about the hosts file (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103084/wildcard-subdomain-on-localhost-using-host-file)

Comment: So i have changed my hosts file to a specific subdomain, so i can check if its working (showing me /asd/): asd.mysite.com , but when i access i get the internal server error - so there is something wrong?

Comment: @Karem take a look at the server's error log to see what is causing the 500 error

Comment: [Fri Jan 10 14:07:34.286006 2014] [proxy:warn] [pid 11952:tid 1676] [client 127.0.0.1:61326] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /index.php. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.